# Determining which account failed to write to a folder

Tags: server, permissions, tomcat

I'm trying to start Jenkins hosted through Tomcat7. The `JENKINS_HOME` variable is pointing to `/opt/jenkins`. The problem I'm having is this: when I try to start the webapp, it fails if `tomcat7` is not the owner of the `/opt/jenkins` folder.

If the permissions on the folder  are `drwxrwxr-x tomcat7:jenkins`, I am able to start the webapp.

If the permissions on the folder are `drwxrwxr-x jenkins:tomcat7`, I am unable to start the webapp.

If `tomcat7` is in the `jenkins` group, should it not have write-access to the folder? Why will the webapp only start if `tomcat7` is the owner?

Answer (score 0):

You can add your user account to a group with the following command:

```
sudo usermod -a -G <group> <username>
```

Do take care not to forget the -a (append) switch this tells usermod to add the group to the groups your user is already in otherwise it would replace all your existing groups with this one.

Note that the groups are read at user login thus you will need to log out and back in again before the change will take effect.

Comment: I've updated the question to be a little bit more specific. The question is more about, why does `tomcat7` need to be the owner of the folder, instead of just being in the group with write permissions?